# Append two arrays having same key inside one array differently

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array in php likes this :

```
$a = [ 1 => [ 0 => 10, 1 => 1 ] ] and $b = [ 1 => [ 0 => 15, 1 => 3 ] ]
```

I have to make a union of these two arrays that resultant array should be like this :

```
$r = [ 1 => [ 0 => 10, 1 => 1 ], 1 => [ 0 => 15, 1 => 3 ] ]
```

Please give me idea how can i achieve this ..

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: This is not possible, you can't have the same index twice.

Comment: You cannot have a array with 2 keys of the same value!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't give same array index....index is unique**

```
$r[] = $a;
$r[] = $b;
```

so your array will be

```
$r = [ [0]=>[1 => [ 0 => 10, 1 => 1 ]], [1] =>[1 => [ 0 => 15, 1 => 3 ] ]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! your solution almost fulfilled my requirement !!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an array with the same key.

If you want to merge values of two arrays, use array_merge:

```
$a = array(
           0 => 10, 
           1 => 1 ) ;
print_r($a);
echo "<br>";

$b = array(0 => 15, 
           1 => 3);

print_r($b);
echo "<br>";

$result = array_merge($a, $b);

print_r($result);
```